# Access Store Value in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I am importing value from store

```
import {store} from '../../store/store'
```

and I have Variable:-

```
let Data = {
  textType: '',
  textData: null
};
```

When i use `console.log(store.state.testData)`

Getting Below result in console:-

```
{__ob__: Observer}
counters:Array(4)
testCounters:Array(0)
__ob__:Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get counters:ƒ reactiveGetter()
set counters:ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get usageUnitCounters:ƒ reactiveGetter()
set usageUnitCounters:ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__:Object
```

and when i directly access `console.log(store.state.testData.testCounters)`

Getting Below result in console:-

```
[__ob__: Observer]
length:0
__ob__:Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__:Array
```

but if i access `console.log(store.state.testData.testCounters)` with setTimeout then i get required value for testCounters.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(tore.state.testData.testCounters);    
}, 13000)
```

But i need to assign **testCounter**  value to ***Data*** variable but as data is not available it pass blank value as defined. How can i wait untill ***testCounters*** Data will be available or do we have any other methods?

```
export { Data }
```

Answer (score 10):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to access `store.state.testData.testCounters` once it's set.

the way you could do that is to use a computed and a watch

```
  computed: {
    testData() {
      return this.$store.state.testData;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    testData: {
      immediate: true,
      deep: false,
      handler(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
      }
    }
  },
```

the watch will trigger once after mounted (because `immediate` is set to `true`, but you can set it to `false`) it will trigger again when the value changes.

On a side note, you can use the spread operator to display the object values without the observables like this:

`console.log({...store.state.testData})`

Comment: Thanks Daniel! but I need to use this in JS file not in Vue component.

Answer (score 1):

As it returns observable you should subscribe the store.

```
 store.subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res) //all state values are available in payload
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
computed: {
    audioPlayerStatus() {
      return this.$store.getters.loadedAudioPlayer;
    }
  },

  watch: {
    '$store.state.loadedAudioPlayer.isTrackPlaying': function() {
      ...
    }
  },
```